# PyQt - Signaling worker in QThread

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, signals

I'm trying to use `QThread`ing in my PyQt application. I have a worker that constantly does something in a loop and occasionally needs to update parameters used in its loop body. I decided to solve the problem using signals. However the parameter update never happens. To demonstrate the problem, consider the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class A(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            pass

    def update(self):
        print("Updating")


class Updater(QObject):
    update_needed = pyqtSignal()


a = A()
u = Updater()
t = QThread()
a.moveToThread(t)

t.started.connect(a.run)
t.finished.connect(a.deleteLater)
u.update_needed.connect(a.update)

t.start()
u.update_needed.emit()
```

At first I thought the problem was that my run method wasn't allowing the `QThread` enough time to process events (even though I read that `QThread` would ensure this automatically - this was why I chose this threading implementation with `moveToThread` instead of subclassing `QThread`).

So I changed the `run` method in `A` to

```
def run(self):
    return True
```

but `update` still didn't get called.

Finally, I tried putting everything in an actual `QApplication` (even though a `QThread` should have its own event loop AFAIK):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = A()
        self.u = Updater()
        t = QThread(self)
        self.a.moveToThread(t)

        t.started.connect(self.a.run)
        t.finished.connect(self.a.deleteLater)
        self.u.update_needed.connect(self.a.update)

        t.start()
        self.u.update_needed.emit()


class A(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            pass

    def update(self):
        print("Updating")


class Updater(QObject):
    update_needed = pyqtSignal()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but this does not run `update` either. Why is the `update_needed` signal not registering?

Comment: change to `t = QThread(self)`

Comment: Doing this only addresses the side problem of the "`QThread` destroyed" error message. It does not fix the key problem addressed in the question.

Comment: I have edited the original question to clarify the issue.

Comment: In both of the code examples shown `A.run` is an infinite loop that never passes control back to the Qt event processing loop.  So regardless of how many queued signals are sent they will never be processed.

Comment: `return True` is not an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried having `A.run` simply `return True` in the second code example you give?

Comment: Also note that in the second example the `QThread` is local to the `MainWindow` ctor -- you need to make it a class variable with `self.t = QThread()`.

Comment: Combining the second example with a `return True` indeed makes the `update` run. I still don't understand why the same didn't work in the first example (since `QThread` is supposed to have its own event loop), but this does solve the issue. Now to figure out how to properly replicate this in my project.

Comment: I suspect the first example didn't work with the `return True` version of `A.run` because you didn't create a `QApplication` of any sort.  `QApplication` does a lot of work -- initialization etc. -- and without that a lot of Qt's functionality might not work as expected.